# How fix the bubble-sort ? It doesn't line up in numerical order

Tags: c

```
#define stdMax 5
#define SWAP(a,b)  {int t; t = a; a=b; b=t;}
typedef struct student {
    char name[100];
    int stdNum;
} Student;

void bubbleSort(int std[], int n );

int main() {
    char text[stdMax][100];
    Student std[stdMax];
    char* temp = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < stdMax; i++) {
        printf("%d   Enter student name / student number: ", i + 1);
        gets(&text[i][0]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < stdMax; i++ ) {
        strcpy_s(std[i].name, 100, strtok_s(&text[i][0], "/",&temp));
        std[i].stdNum = atoi(strtok_s(NULL,"/",&temp));
    }

    bubbleSort(std, 5);

    for (int i = 0; i < stdMax; i++) {
        printf("%d %s\n", std[i].stdNum, std[i].name);
    }
}


void bubbleSort(int *std, int n) 
{
    
        int i, j;
        
        for (i = n; i > 1; i--)
        {
            for (j = 1; j < i; j++)
            {
                if (std[j - 1] > std[j])
                {
                    SWAP(std[j - 1], std[j]);
                
                }
            }
        }
    
}
```

ex) student/1234,
I'd like to put 5 in order of number size. However, when this code is executed, it only outputs as it is entered. I don't know which part is wrong. I think there's something wrong with the bubble sort, so I'd appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: You're only sorting the first five items. Why is that? *EDIT* Wait a minute, you're not sorting anything. You need to swap `Student` structs, not just the numbers

Comment: `gets` ...oh no - please don't - use `fgets` instead

Comment: Turn warnings of your compiler ON!

Comment: OT: `bubbleSort(std, 5);` --> `bubbleSort(std, stdMax);`

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with an array of `Student`, but the `bubbleSort` function is for sorting `int`. Mismatch here.

```
#define stdMax 5
#define SWAP(a,b)  {Student t; t = a; a=b; b=t;}
typedef struct student {
    char name[100];
    int stdNum;
} Student;

void bubbleSort(Student std[], int n );

/* omit: same as original */

void bubbleSort(Student *std, int n) 
{
    
        int i, j;
        
        for (i = n; i > 1; i--)
        {
            for (j = 1; j < i; j++)
            {
                if (std[j - 1].stdNum > std[j].stdNum)
                {
                    SWAP(std[j - 1], std[j]);
                
                }
            }
        }
    
}
```